# Converting aligned array uint8[8] to double

Tags: ios, c, double, bit-manipulation, core-foundation

I am facing a bit of a challenge trying to convert an aligned array `uint8[8]` to a `double`.
It was particularly easy to convert `uint8[4]` to `long` with bit-operations, but i understand that the `double` can become messy in terms of a sign bit?

In Java i simply use `ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble()` but i assume its not that easy in C.

I tried to implement this code, but the last command gives the error `Expression is not assignable` and `Shift count >= width of type`

```
long tempHigh = 0; 
long tempLow = 0;
double sum = 0;
tempHigh |= buffer[0] & 0xFF;
tempHigh <<= 8;
tempHigh |= buffer[1] & 0xFF;
tempHigh <<= 8;
tempHigh |= buffer[2] & 0xFF;
tempHigh <<= 8;
tempHigh |= buffer[3] & 0xFF;

tempLow |= buffer[4] & 0xFF;
tempLow <<= 8;
tempLow |= buffer[5] & 0xFF;
tempLow <<= 8;
tempLow |= buffer[6] & 0xFF;
tempLow <<= 8;
tempLow |= buffer[7] & 0xFF;

sum |= ((tempHigh & 0xFFFF) <<= 32) + (tempLow & 0xFFFF);
```

How can this procedure be done correctly *or* just resolve the error i have made?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portable way to do it is to read out the sign, exponent, and mantissa values into integer variables with bitwise arithmetic, then call `ldexp` to apply the exponent.

OK, here's some code. Beware it might have mismatched parentheses or off-by-one errors.

```
unsigned char x[8]; // your input; code assumes little endian
long mantissa = ((((((x[6]%16)*256 + x[5])*256 + x[4])*256 + x[3])*256 + x[2])*256 + x[1])*256 + x[0];
int exp = x[7]%128*16 + x[6]/16 - 1023;
int sign = 1-x[7]/128*2;
double y = sign*ldexp(0x1p53 + mantissa, exp-53);
```

Comment: Could you give an example? I see the sign issue now.

Comment: Do i have to flip everything in case of big endian?

Comment: You have to flip the array offsets if the *data* is big endian. The code is 100% independent of the machine endianness, tho.

Answer (score 3):

`double` is a floating-point type; it doesn't support bitwise operations such as `|`.

You could do something like:

```
double sum;

memcpy(&sum, buffer, sizeof(sum));
```

But be aware of endianness issues.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternativ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about a union?  Write to the long part as you have, then the double is automagically correct.  Something like this:

```
union 
{
   double sum;
   struct
   {
       long tempHigh;
       long tempLow;
   }v;
 }u;

 u.v.tempHigh = 0; 
 u.v.tempHigh |= buffer[0] & 0xFF;
 u.v.tempHigh <<= 8;
 u.v.tempHigh |= buffer[1] & 0xFF;
 u.v.tempHigh <<= 8;
 u.v.tempHigh |= buffer[2] & 0xFF;
 u.v.tempHigh <<= 8;
 u.v.tempHigh |= buffer[3] & 0xFF;

 u.v.tempLow |= buffer[4] & 0xFF;
 u.v.tempLow <<= 8;
 u.v.tempLow |= buffer[5] & 0xFF;
 u.v.tempLow <<= 8;
 u.v.tempLow |= buffer[6] & 0xFF;
 u.v.tempLow <<= 8;
 u.v.tempLow |= buffer[7] & 0xFF;

 printf("%f", u.sum);
```